# How to evaluate $|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+|a_3|^2+\dots$ using elementary symmetric polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

Given the values of the elementary symmetric polynomials $$e_1(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n),\, e_2(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n),\, \dots,\, e_n(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$$ of $n$ complex numbers $a_i\in\mathbb C,$ I want to find the value of $$|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+\dots+|a_n|^2.$$
I know this can be easily done when $a_1\in\mathbb R,$ because it simplifies to $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2-2\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}a_ia_j=e_1^2-2e_2,$$
but with complex numbers I can't find such an expression.

Comment: Even though that expression is symmetric, doesn't the fact that it's not a polynomial mean you're going to have to go beyond addition and multiplication to do so? Or are you already assuming that, and expecting such an answer?

Comment: I want to evaluate this using addition, multiplication, subtraction, division and conjugation.

Comment: Ah, okay, conjugation is allowed. Seems like it should be possible then.

Comment: This question does need context and clarification. Relevant information includes where this problem came from. It would help if you could define what an elementary symmetric polynomial is.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum |a_k|^2$ is not a polynomial function in $a_k$, and not every symmetric but non-polynomial function can be expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Taking for example the case $n=2$ with $e_1, e_2 \in \mathbb R$:

- if the roots are real then $|a_1|^2 + |a_2|^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 = (a_1+a_2)^2 - 2a_1a_2 = e_1^2 - 2 e_2$;
- if the roots are complex (which implies $e_2 \gt 0$) then they must be conjugates, so $|a_1|=|a_2|=\sqrt{e_2}$ and $|a_1|^2 + |a_2|^2 = 2 e_2$.

Since the expressions are not the same in the two cases, there exists no polynomial or rational function in $e_1, e_2$ that represents $|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2$, even if conjugates $\bar e_1, \bar e_2$ are also allowed.